# How to add a recursive component to my query to add x amount of dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I have to segment users into 4 categories based on their last logins.
each category represent how recent was their last login (i.e. last 28 days, between 29 and 45 days, etc)
If I want to figure it out for today, its simple. However, I need snapshots for the past 60 days. In other words,how many users logged in the last 28 days, 60 days ago. I'll need data for the past 60 days.
naturally, I am trying to save my self some time and instead of using 60 UNION all, and 60 declare dates. Can it be achieve with a WITH loop?

Here's an example with two arbitray dates (ideally id have all the 60 days before nov13th):

```
DECLARE @dDate AS DATE = '2018-11-13'
DECLARE @dDate2 AS DATE = '2018-10-13'
SELECT @dDate as First_Date
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN subquery2.Total_Days <=28 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) As GOOD
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN subquery2.Total_Days BETWEEN 28 AND 85 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) As BAD
FROM (
    SELECT *, DATEDIFF(dd,subquery1.Max_login_time,@dDate) As Total_Days
        FROM(
            SELECT DISTINCT emails
                ,MAX(login_time) AS Max_login_time
            FROM #test1
            WHERE login_time < @dDate
            GROUP BY emails
            ) AS subquery1
        ) as subquery2
UNION ALL
SELECT @dDate2 as First_Date
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN subquery2.Total_Days <=28 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) As GOOD
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN subquery2.Total_Days BETWEEN 28 AND 85 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) As BAD
FROM (
    SELECT *, DATEDIFF(dd,subquery1.Max_login_time,@dDate2) As Total_Days
        FROM(
            SELECT DISTINCT emails
                ,MAX(login_time) AS Max_login_time
            FROM #test1
            WHERE login_time < @dDate2
            GROUP BY emails
            ) AS subquery1
        ) as subquery2
```

Now if i go on with this logic I will have to include 58 more union alls and @declare dates which is obviously extremely inefficient.
I read a bit on recursive CTE tables which seem to be just what I need but cant apply the logic. 
Here's a sample of the output from the union all. The second row gives me information in the past which would not take into consideration loggins after that date.

```
+------------+------+-----+--+
| First_date | GOOD | BAD |  |
+------------+------+-----+--+
| 2018-11-13 |    2 |   2 |  |
| 2018-10-13 |    3 |   1 |  |
+------------+------+-----+--+
```

Here's a sample data that im working from:

```
CREATE TABLE #test1 (
    login_time DATE
    ,emails CHAR(30)
    )

INSERT INTO #test1
VALUES  ('2018-11-10', 'a@gmail.com')
,('2018-10-01', 'a@gmail.com')
,('2018-09-01', 'a@gmail.com')
,('2018-01-01', 'a@gmail.com')
,('2018-08-01', 'b@gmail.com')
,('2018-07-01', 'b@gmail.com')
,('2018-09-01', 'b@gmail.com')
,('2018-04-01', 'c@gmail.com')
,('2018-10-01', 'c@gmail.com')
,('2018-10-02', 'c@gmail.com')
,('2018-11-10', 'd@gmail.com')
,('2018-09-18', 'd@gmail.com')
,('2018-11-09', 'd@gmail.com')
,('2018-07-01', 'd@gmail.com')
```

Comment: I don't think you need recursion here at all. Just group by the date of login_time and adjust the where clause to get all the dates you want.

Comment: You're overthinking this issue. Set a date range between two dates and write one select statement. Group by the dates of each day, convert them to a VARCHAR(101) or similar date format so it only contains the date and not the time.

Comment: It won't work because this exercise is to go back in time and find out how user login activity. its like seeing a snapshot of a specific day in the past. @SeanLange

Comment: So you're passing 60 date parameters too? `@dDate`, `@dDate2`,`@dDate3`,...`@dDate59`,`@dDate60`? Just have `@dDateStart` and `@dDateEnd` and then use `BETWEEN`. If you need to also return the value of every date between them, consider using a [Calendar Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/).

Comment: @haag1 Unfortunately not as simple as this, this wont give me the result im looking for. Say i want to know how many users logged in the past 20 days 40 days ago, it wont work

Comment: @Ismafoot well then you need to re explain the situation with some sample data, because everyone is suggesting the same solution to you. Either we are confused or you didn't explain your situation well enough

Comment: It would work. That is the point of aggregation, to separate the data into groups. But we can't really help you here because there just isn't enough information. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: @Larnu I have never used the calendar table. The between clause wont work, because its just going to give me logins between the two dates which i dont need. i need to go back in time and find out the # of users loggins based on the criteria

Comment: why don't you filter using the between clause to get your 40 days back worth of data and then use a separate date parameter that can be used to filter the previous data further for example 20 days worth of data from the 40 days in the past data.

Comment: @haag1 ill give an example of output

Comment: Sorry guys, i am having difficulty making my question clear...

Comment: Yes....it is unclear because you aren't posting details. See this article on how to make this better. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange I edited my first paragraph hoping this can make it more clear.

Comment: Try reading the details at the link I have posted twice. We need table definitions, sample data and desired output.

Comment: @SeanLange Ive just edited the whole question to include sample data and an output example. I didint figure out how to use the CSV to SQL converter though so I just included the INSERT data ... hope this helps now

Comment: The inserts is by far preferred. :) So now we have excellent sample data. What do you expect as output from that sample data? I am missing something in the explanation of requirements.

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you! So im expecting dates, good and bad columns.
Ill have 60 rows(60 dates in the past). So how many logged in 28 days ago with base date nov 13th. Then how many logged in 28 days ago with base date nov 12th and so on for 60 days. Im pretty sure its a WITH  loop . Recursive or not im unsure.

Comment: Wait a minute....you want a result set with 60 dates and the count of rows from your table on each date? Which 60 dates do you want? Today's date and the previous 60 days?

Comment: @SeanLange yesterday's date and the previous 60 days.

Answer (score 0):

A loop is definitely not the right way to go here. What you want to use instead is a tally or numbers table. Jeff Moden has a great article on the topic here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

I actually keep one around on my system as a view. It is stupidly fast and incredibly useful. My view looks like this.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
GO
```

Then to use it with your sample it is quite simple.

```
select convert(date, DATEADD(day, t.N - 60, dateadd(day, -1, getdate())))
    , count(login_time)
from cteTally t
left join #test1 t1 on t1.login_time = convert(date, DATEADD(day, t.N - 60, dateadd(day, -1, getdate())))
where t.N <= 60
group by convert(date, DATEADD(day, t.N - 60, dateadd(day, -1, getdate())))
```

This query is completely dynamic in that the dates returned will changed based on the current system date. Also notice, that in the sample data you posted there are seven rows that are not counted because they are earlier than 60 days prior to today.

--EDIT--

Since you can't create a view you can use the cte inline. I took out the last join because you don't need that many rows. Something like this.

```
WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E2
    )

select convert(date, DATEADD(day, t.N - 60, dateadd(day, -1, getdate())))
    , count(login_time)
from cteTally t
left join #test1 t1 on t1.login_time = convert(date, DATEADD(day, t.N - 60, dateadd(day, -1, getdate())))
where t.N <= 60
group by convert(date, DATEADD(day, t.N - 60, dateadd(day, -1, getdate())))
```

As for incorporating this with your code, I don't understand what you want as output which is why I asked so many times. You don't want to use your code as it sits. It is loop based which you should avoid. It needs to be replaced by a set based approach along these lines.

Comment: my permission is denied when creating the view... and tbh im not sure how to  incroporate the code into my own code to combine the WHERE conditions... (still very new in SQL)

Comment: the output throws the last 60 days user activity information and are segmented in categories based on a predetermined set of criteria. i have to make inferences on whether people where more active before or now. To do this I need to know the loggin status for the past 60 days. I only need to do it once because it was never done before. Starting today, ill just run a simple query for every day without any use of UNION or loops.